# Selected Picklist Values Not Inserted When Creating Record in Salesforce LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am working on a custom creation page using Salesforce LWC. This involves a custom object and picklist fields. I am aiming to insert all values upon saving, but only Name value is inserted. Upon checking the browser's developer console, I can see the selected value per picklist field. How can I insert all these values?

Meanwhile, below are the latest codes I have:

**customObjectLWC.html**

```
<template>

    <lightning-card>   
    
        <template if:true={custObjRecord}>

            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Custom Object Record</h2>
            </header>
        
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">    
               
                <lightning-input type="text" 
                                 name="CustomObjectName" 
                                 label="Custom Object Name"
                                 value={custObjRecord.Name} 
                                 onchange={handleCustObjNameChange} 
                                 class="slds-m-right_small" 
                                 required>

                </lightning-input>
                       
            </div>   
            
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        
                <lightning-combobox label="Picklist A" 
                    name="PicklistA" 
                    onchange={handlePicklistAChange} 
                    options={picklistAValues} 
                    placeholder="--None--" 
                    value={selectedPicklistA}
                    required>
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br/>
        
            </div>
            
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        
                <lightning-combobox label="Picklist B" 
                    name="PicklistB" 
                    onchange={handlePicklistBChange} 
                    options={controllingValues} 
                    placeholder="--None--" 
                    value={selectedPicklistB}
                    class="slds-m-right_small"
                    required>
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br/>
        
            </div>
        
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        
                <lightning-combobox label="Picklist C" 
                    name="PicklistC"
                    onchange={handlePicklistCChange} 
                    options={dependentValues} 
                    placeholder="--None--" 
                    value={selectedPicklistC}
                    disabled={isEmpty}>
                </lightning-combobox>
                <br/>  
        
            </div>                
                                              
            </div>            
                    
            <div class="slds-p-top_large">
            <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer slds-size_1-of-1">
                <div class="forceChangeRecordTypeFooter">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={createRecord}></lightning-button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </template>

    
</lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

**customObjectLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CUSTOM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Custom_Object__c';

import createCustomObject from '@salesforce/apex/CustomObjectController.createCustomObject';
    
    export default class customObjectLWC extends LightningElement {

    @track custObjRecord = CUSTOM_OBJECT;

    @track selectedPicklistA;
    @track picklistAValues = [];
    
    @track controllingValues = [];
    @track dependentValues = [];
    @track selectedPicklistB;
    @track selectedPicklistC;
    @track isEmpty = false;
    
    @track error;
    controlValues;
    totalDependentValues = [];
    @track data;
    
    handleCustObjNameChange(event) {
        this.custObjRecord.Name = event.detail.value;
        console.log('Custom Object Name' + this.custObjRecord.Name);
    }


    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId'})
    picklistAPicklistValues({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.error = null;
    
            let picklistAOptions = [{label:'--None--', value:'--None--'}];
   
   
            data.picklistFieldValues.Picklist_A__c.values.forEach(key => {
                picklistAOptions.push({
                    label : key.label,
                    value: key.value
                })
            });

            this.picklistAValues = picklistAOptions;

        }

        else if(error) {
            this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId'})
    itemPicklistValues({error, data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.error = null;
                       
            let pBOptions = [{label:'--None--', value:'--None--'}];
                      
                      
            data.picklistFieldValues.Picklist_B__c.values.forEach(key => {
                pBOptions.push({
                    label : key.label,
                    value: key.value
                })
            });

            this.controllingValues = pBOptions;

            let pCOptions = [{label:'--None--', value:'--None--'}];

            this.controlValues = data.picklistFieldValues.Picklist_C__c.controllerValues;
            this.totalDependentValues = data.picklistFieldValues.Picklist_C__c.values;
            this.totalDependentValues.forEach(key => {
                pCOptions.push({
                    label : key.label,
                    value: key.value
                })
            });

            this.dependentValues = pCOptions;

        }
        else if(error) {
            this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
        }
    }

    handlePicklistAChange(event) {
        this.selectedPicklistA = event.target.value;
        console.log('Picklist A' + this.selectedPicklistA);
    }

    handlePicklistBChange(event) {
        this.selectedPicklistB = event.target.value;
        console.log('Picklist B' + this.selectedPicklistB);
        this.isEmpty = false;
        let dependValues = [];
    
        if(this.selectedPicklistB) {
            if(this.selectedPicklistB === '--None--') {
                this.isEmpty = true;
                dependValues = [{label:'--None--', value:'--None--'}];
                this.selectedPicklistB = null;
                this.selectedPicklistC = null;
                return;
            }
        
            this.totalDependentValues.forEach(conValues => {
                if(conValues.validFor[0] === this.controlValues[this.selectedPicklistB]) {
                    dependValues.push({
                        label: conValues.label,
                        value: conValues.value
                    })
                }
            })

            this.dependentValues = dependValues;
        }
    }

    handlePicklistCChange(event) {
        this.selectedPicklistC = event.target.value;
        console.log('Picklist C' + this.selectedPicklistC);
    }

    createRecord() {

        createCustomObject({
            newCustomObjRecord: this.custObjRecord
        })
        .then(result => {
            
            this.custObjRecord = {};
            

            console.log('result ===> '+result);
            
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success!!',
                message: 'Custom Object Record Created Successfully!!',
                variant: 'success'
            }),);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomObjectController.cls**

```
public with sharing class CustomObjectController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Custom_Object__c createCustomObject(Custom_Object__c newCustomObjRecord) {
       insert newCustomObjRecord;
       return newCustomObjRecord;
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned other field values to the record `custObjRecord`.

```
handlePicklistAChange(event) {
    this.custObjRecord.A_Picklist_Field__c = event.target.value;
}
```

Also if you assign the name property with the field API name. You can write a generic handler too, like.

```
handlePicklistChange(event) {
    this.custObjRecord[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

With this, you can avoid creating repetitive `onchange` handlers

---

As you are simply inserting a record, you can use [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write) from the uiRecordApi library instead of the apex.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response! Will try your answer, let me just modify my codes. As for the approach in inserting records, I am still looking for a better approach since I am planning to make my codes handle bulk insert (since I would also like to consider differences between Apex and Javascript when it comes to handling capacity and limitation) and other enhancements.

Comment: if you are looking for bulk then definitely apex is an option.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, and picklist values are inserted now. Thanks again for your help and recommendations :))